# Is it safe to manipulate with DOM (using JavaScript) to move up in the search results?

Tags: seo, javascript, googlebot

I have some text written for SEO purposes and it is located right after the opening body tag, so it is at the top of the page. That doesn't look great so this text is moved to the bottom of the page with JavaScript.

As far as I know Googlebots don't understand JavaScript perfectly so they see this text at the top of the page and user sees this text in his browser at the bottom of the page.

Is it safe and does it make sense or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not safe. You are doing this *explicitly for the manipulations of your search results*. This is *exactly* what search engines do not want. Doing this make you potentially subject to penalty including a possible sitewide ban from the search results.

So, bad idea.